# Unexpected 'else' syntax error

Tags: bash, variables

When running my script I get the following error:

> unexpected 'else' syntax error.

Everything seems fine to me

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
if [$#>1] then
        perl blockingsessionsprojse.pl $1
else
        perl blockingsessionsprojse.pl 300
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 errors in your code. First of all, you use `if` keyword wrong.

```
$ help if
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
```

Note the `;`. So it should be:

```
if [$#>1]; then
```

Second, you need add a whitespace after `[` and before `]`, and also around the `>` operator (which needs to be `-gt` for numeric comparisons) so altogether `if` condition should be:

```
if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
if [ $# -gt 1 ] 
then
        perl blockingsessionsprojse.pl $1
else
        perl blockingsessionsprojse.pl 300
fi
```